# Is it ok not to have oil to the full mark?

Tags: oil, oil-change

I had my oil changed at the dealership for my 2013 Corolla. It is full synthetic oil. The next day, I checked the oil on a cold engine before I started it for the day. The level is not the max but it is not full, ether. Is it ok if I just leave the level at this point?

[image]

Comment: Does your car manual say to check the oil when it's cold or hot? Motor oil expands when hot, which may bring it up to the full level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is completely fine as long as it is between the high and low marks.

That said, if you take it back to where you got the oil changed at and tell them it looks a bit low, I'd bet they'd top it off for you. They want to keep you as a customer and it is really a small amount of oil which they didn't include in the first place.

Comment: It's really hard to get there because of my job. My oil changes are 10k which is about 6-8 months for me. Will it be ok at that level for that long?

Comment: Absolutely no issue.

Answer (score 1):

You may not have the car on a perfectly level surface which may be causing the slightly low reading.

I would not worry about that as long as it stays there and is not using oil over time. Having to add a liter every 1000 miles is more of a cause for concern.